# Schengen visa for Denmark

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

I would like to visit my cousin and his family in Denmark. I applied for a visa and was refused. I submitted all the required document except that I didn't submit an letter of approved leave.

Is it necessary to submit a letter?

Comment: Approved leave is not always necessary.  Which items were checked on your refusal notice?

Comment: Your intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertain

Comment: I would like to apply again, Can I re apply right away? Or how many months should I apply again?

Comment: You can reapply right away however based on the reason you were denied for, you should be well prepared before reapplying. If it was only the letter, they _could_ have waited for you to submit it instead of denying you straight away. You may have a weak application and ties to your home country? Don't rush into another denial/refusal.

Comment: @SheikPaul Do they actually wait for you to submit more documents to back up a poor application? I was under the impression that they just evaluate the application they received, and don't engage in a back-and-forth with the applicant

Comment: Please provide a scan of your refusal notice.

Comment: @DavidRicherby They do at their discretion. The French Consulate in DC did that for me in 2015 however it was not a **poor** application. Simply a missing document.

Comment: @SheikPaul Missing along the lines of your application essentially saying "Please see the attached copy of document X" and you'd forgotten to include the document, or missing in the sense of them saying, "Well, you claim Y but we need some kind of documentary evidence of that"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby if they think a SINGLE piece of evidence can prevent a refusal they have the option (but not the obligation) to ask for it. But what we mostly see on this site is that the application is doomed beyond what a single piece of evidence can repair. This question being a nice case in point.

Comment: @jonathanreez what do you mean? I will send the refusal letter? And where do I send it?

Comment: Can I inquire or ask the reason why I was refused to the Danish Immigration Service?